# What determines Google chrome security in websites

Tags: google-chrome, security, web

When you open a new tab in google chrome to the left side their is a secur or not secure banner that displays, I was wondering if anyone knows why or how to make a website display secure ?

Comment: Serve it over HTTPS with a valid certificate.

Comment: Oh thank you. All I needed